# Google Sheets dynamic conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to do dynamic conditional formatting in GS.

This is my formula in "Conditional formatting:

`=$G145:$G146=MAX($G145:$G146)`

I want to be able to drag the conditional formatting across the rows. Basically I want to highlight which cell in in Range G145-G146 is higher. But then drag it across the Column (Higher of Column H, Higher of column I, Higher of column J and so on).

[image]

Picture two:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. But you don't 'drag' it.

1: Select the hole range you want to include.
2: Right click and click conditional formatting
3: Choose custom formula
4: Adjust the formula below to the same range you selected

```
=max(arrayformula($G$5:$Z))
```

If this is not what you are after then i misunderstood.

EDIT:

1: Select the hole range you want to include.
2: Right click and click conditional formatting
3: Choose higer then
4: Paste this in the formula bar

```
={G145,G146}
```

, could be ; depends on the country.

Comment: This is what I think he wants ! Nice

Comment: May be I am not doing some thing correct. Its highlighting all the cells. =max(arrayformula(G145:J146)). Top row is row 146 and below row is row 146

Comment: I have attached picture #2. I want which cell is greater: G145 or G146

Comment: Ahh so.. see my update. The formula above shows the higerst number in the hole dataset. (if you lock the rang with $ signs, that is why everything is colerd in your setup)

Comment: I see another solution. Maybee my bad but the way you show on your screenshot what you want was notclear to me. Did not know this was row 145/146.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
=G145=max(G$145:G$146)
```

[image]